# how to pin vscode IDE . So, watching Youtube tutorial my vscode IDE dont get in background

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am learning a **Youtube tutorial**. Whenever Instructor do coding ,I also want to code simultaneously but when **I press pause or play** My **VScode goes background** . So, I have to **repeated get vscode from taskbar** which is annoying. I want to  PIN VScode , so whenever I pause or play it can not go to background. I **tried split mood** (youtube Left hand side and VScode RHS ) but it make **youtube screen so small** that i can not see code of intructor.

what to do? : I want **to PIN VS code screen**

**Any other solutions** which can solve my task **are welcome.**

Comment: use a second monitor or a 4K monitor

Comment: thanks but i dont have .